# Is it possible to include statically linked libraries in other libraries in C/C++?

Tags: c++

In my project I have some shared code in a statically linked library that is used by several subprojects, each of which building its own executable. I use `ar` to create the library from the `.o` files. Part of the shared code depends on statically linked third party libraries.

Currently, I have to include all the third party libraries in each makefile (for each executable) and pass them to `g++`. Is it possible to include these libraries in the one library shared by the subproject, so I don't have to reference them explicitly when building the different executables? Or is there something wrong with my approach in general?

Comment: "I have [...] statically linked", "create the shared library", "use ar to create the shared"... There seem to be contradictions about what is shared/static.

Comment: With "shared library" I mean the .a file shared by the subprojects. It is a statically linked library. I edited the question to make that clear.

Comment: Sure, you can use `ar` to create one huge mega-archive. You can also use tools like pkg-config to keep track of dependencies for you.

Comment: "Shared library" is a standard term with a fixed meaning, and it's not what you seem to be using. Please use standard terminology.

Comment: Static libraries are not linked at all. They are mechanical collections of object files. Statically linked dynamic libraries exist but you don't want to touch them.

Comment: 'Nest statically linked libraries' is not the same as ' include these libraries in the one library shared by the subproject', and it is therefore a poor choice of title. I suggest you amend it.

Comment: MSVC can do just that (via pragma comment, which gets embedded in the object files). I always wondered why GCC can't.

Comment: @n.m. Statically linked dynamic libraries? You mean the [stub libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2761783/183120) of dynamic libraries?

Comment: @legends2k https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Statically+linked+shared+libraries%22

Comment: It might be operating system specific (e.g. dynamic libraries `*.dll` in Windows are not the same as shared libraries `*.so` on Linux)

Comment: @n.m. Statically and dynamically linking should refer to the linking process, a shared library is constructed by linking and could so be linked by static or dynamic linking. Then when using the library one could use static or dynamic linking, but that's not something that is inherent for the library - it's just a way it's used. Fx the linux kernel dynamically links in `.o` file when modules are loaded so you could certainly dynamically link with an `.a` file, also one could probably persuade the linker to link statically with a `.so` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to pack all the static libraries you are using in one big library. You don't want that.

The common method of dealing with the situation is defining *variables* in your top level makefile, or in an .inc file included by several makefiles:

```
MY_LIBS = -lOne -lTwo
MY_LDFLAGS = -L /path/to/libs
```

and then adding these variables to standard variables

```
LDLIBS += $(MY_LIBS)
LDFLAGS += $(MY_LDFLAGS)
```

Variables above are used by GNU Make implicit link rules; if you are using your own rules, be sure to use these variables, like this:

```
...
g++ $^ $(LDLIBS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

Look at several makefiles from established open source projects for inspiration.

References:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Using-Variables.html
- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to do it this way. I will probably have some trouble with relative paths in the makefiles (which I tried to avoid by stuffing everything in a big library) but I guess I should fix the paths anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Not the way you seem to want. Basically static libraries are just a bunch of object files to be linked in and there's no way one object file could imply automatic inclusion of another object file. Consequently a static library cannot call for another static library to be automatically included in the link. For dynamic libraries on the other hand, the library itself may refer to another library that would (dynamically) be linked in.

What you **could** do is to use an implicit linker script in place of the static library that states which library should be included. For example in `libfoo.a`:

```
INPUT(-lreal-foo)
INPUT(-lbar)
```

Would mean that `-lfoo` tells the linker to include `-lreal-foo` (which would mean your original `.a` file) and `-lbar` which would mean the library it depends on.

The working is that whenever the linker is told to link with `libfoo.a` it will when it realize it's not an archive (ie `.a` file) or an object file it will try to interpret it as a linker script. The `INPUT` commands then instructs the linker to include those file as they would be specified at that point, specifically if they are on the form `-lFILE` it will act as if `-lFILE` was included on the command line.

Comment: Can such a linker script be used just like a static library?

Comment: @PaulGroke Yes, if the linker doesn't recognize it as an object file or archive it will try to interpret it as an implicit linker script. In fact this is already used for some of the libraries on (some) x86-64 linux.